# iPhone and GZip

Tags: iphone, gzip, nsdata

Now I know that xCode automaticly does the GZip decrompession for you within:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URL];
```

And it does work if I point to a Gzip file on my server. But since my content is dynamic, I have a PHP script that rather then create a gzip file like so:

```
$zp   = gzopen($file, "r");
$data = gzread($zp, $filesize);
gzclose($zp);
```

I encode my own data with:

```
echo gzencode($data, 9);
```

With this I add the following headers:

```
header("Content-Type: application/x-gzip");
header("Content-Encoding: gzip");
header("Accepts-Encoding: gzip");
```

When I browse to the URL, my browser wants to download the file automatically and I am able to unzip it on my Mac and view it's content. However when I try to read it through xCode it won't work.

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URL];
NSString *content = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog (content); //returns only data when pointed directly to a Gzip file
```

Am I forgetting something?

Comment: yeah. you're forgetting to accept your answers!! (sorry couldn't resist!)

Comment: You are using NSLog incorrectly. Use a format string: `NSLog(@"%@",content);`

Comment: Just out of interest, why would you want to do this? Wouldn't using mod_deflate be much simpler and not require any manual intervention like this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you download something with content type application/x-gzip, the url loading system will not decompress it for you. I think the `data` that you received is still gzip encoded.

You can use my NSData additions to deal with this. See http://github.com/st3fan/cocoa-utils/blob/master/src/NSDataGZipAdditions.m

Comment: upvoted for being unbelievably helpful - thanks for the category!