# gzencode php to objective c nsdata

Tags: php, objective-c, gzip

My question is similar to here:

[iPhone and GZip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159575/iphone-and-gzip)

only, I get no result.

I gzipped the data in PHP:

```
$gztext = gzcompress($text,9);
var_dump(base64_encode($gztext));
```

and tried to decode in iOS:

```
NSString *encodedGzippedString = @"K0ktLlFIzSspqlTQ09MDYTCloKcApWEEGBkaGZuYAAA=";
NSData *decodedGzippedData     = [NSData dataByBase64DecodingString:encodedGzippedString];
NSData *unGzippedJsonData = [decodedGzippedData gzipInflate];
if(unGzippedJsonData){
    NSString* unGzippedJsonString  = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:unGzippedJsonData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];       
    if(unGzippedJsonString)
         NSLog(@"Result: %@", unGzippedJsonString);
    else
       NSLog(@"string error");
}
else NSLog(@"gzip error");
```

The result is "gzip error"

Answer (score 1):

This works as expected:

```
NSString* base64Str = @"eJwrSS0uUShJrQARxSUAKVwFhg==";
NSData* gzData = [NSData dataFromBase64String:base64Str];
NSData* flatData = [gzData gzipInflate];
NSString* result = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(const char*) flatData.bytes];
```

With [NSData+Base64](http://projectswithlove.com/projects/NSData_Base64.zip) and [NSData+Compression](https://github.com/geoffgarside/Git.framework/tree/develop/Source/Category/NSData) categories

Comment: thanks, but it did not work for me with the string above K0ktLlFIzSspqlTQ09MDYTCloKcApWEEGBkaGZuYAAA= . Unfortunately for this thread, I was able to compress using bzip and no longer need to spend my time on this.

thanks anyway though

Answer (score 0):

My situation is that I would like to decode a gzip file. By following the answer of @sigman, I can decode the gzip file.
 For instance,
 
`NSString * gfile = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"randomgzip.c.gz"];
NSData * gdata = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:gfile];
NSData * flatData = [gdata gzipInflate];`