# decompress gzip type response from json web-service

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, gzip

I'm getting GZIP type compressed response from web-service. Can you please help me how to decompress or decode such response.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init]; 

[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];

  **strong text** [request setValue:@"gzip" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Encoding"];

[request setTimeoutInterval:30];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"]; 
[request setHTTPBody:requestData];
```

Waiting for your answers.
Thanks in adv.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159575/iphone-and-gzip

Answer (score 2):

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URL];
```

This will automatically decompress the content if it was gzipped.

Comment: yes, i'm receiving bytes - converting nsdata to string - gives encoded string -                this link of my code . http://pastebin.com/f3GDzi4a        thanks.

Comment: How can you state that if the documentation on NSData doesn't mention any gzip related things?