# Compressed json to json coversion in iOS

Tags: ios, json

Can i get json object form compressed json in iOS ?
is there any way to convert it?

Comment: Its not a zip file, it is a format (compressed Json)

Answer (score 0):

If it's gzip compressed, it will automatically be converted. Take a look at this thread:

[iPhone and GZip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159575/iphone-and-gzip)

Basically, just:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URL];
```