# Using gzcompress in PHP; need to be able to uncompress on iPhone iOS5.0

Tags: ios, gzip

I'm using `gzcompress()` to compress JSON data in PHP and then base64 encoding it to send it into an iPhone app via Amazon SQS queue
Having some troubles figuring out how to uncompress this data on the iPhone (iOS).

When I receive it on the iPhone, I base64 decode it using the category NSData+Base64 and then try to decompress it using godzippa. however this does not work. Is there another library that I should use or another method.

I've searched on the forum and found just one post on similar problem, but found no answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159575/iphone-and-gzip

Answer (score 0):

thank you so much for this.. I was finally able to do the gzip uncompress using the NSData+Compression category at https://github.com/schacon/igithub/blob/master/CocoaGit/Util/NSData+Compression.h .. will keep your's handy too. Thank you again!